# Sum of coefficients of a unit vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a quick question for verification.

I found this statement in my notes:

Given an orthonormal basis$\left ( v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n} \right )$, every unit vector $x$ can be written as the linear combination of these vectors, i.e. $\sum \lambda _{i}v_{i}$ with the coefficients $\lambda _{i}\geq 0$ and $\sum \lambda _{i}=1$.

Shouldn't it be $\sum \lambda _{i}^{2}=1$ instead? I found that's what $\left \langle \sum \lambda _{i}v_{i},\sum \lambda _{i}v_{i} \right \rangle$ would reduce to. ¨

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, definitely. Easy to find a counterexample to the other formula.

Comment: @DivergentQueries great, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the answer depends on the norm that is defined on the vector space.

For the Euclidean norm, defined as,

$$||\mathbf{x}||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2}$$
where $\lambda_i$ are the components with respect to an orthonormal basis, than 
$||\mathbf{x}||=1$ iff $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2=1$.

but for a different norm we can have a different condition, As an example for the [Manhattan norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm):
$$
||\mathbf{x}||=\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|
$$

we have 
$$
||\mathbf{x}||=1 \quad \mbox{iff} \quad \sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|=1
$$

Anyway the condition $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i=1$ is wrong for any norm because this sum can be negative.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel bad about deleting this question now. I thought it wasn't worth keeping up, but your answer is insightful.

Comment: Note that the euclidean norm is the only norm that can be derived from an inner product so, if you know that the this is the case, than your conclusion is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it should be just $\sum \lambda_i^2=1$ for a vector to have unit norm.

The conditions $\lambda_i \geq 0$ and $\sum \lambda_i=1$ specify the convex hull of the vectors. In case they are orthonormal, it would be the standard $(N-1)$-dimensional simplex in $N$-dimensional space, with the basis vectors being its vertices.

Comment: Thank you! I hope you don't mind me deleting this question as I think it is of poor usefulness.

Comment: @John11 The point is that someone may accidentally come up with the same question, and here's the answer. But it certainly is up to you whether to delete it or not :)